# Environment variable to recognise if deployed on Mobile App or Web App?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic5

Hi I am using Ionic 5 with Angular. I have a mobile app that I am currently developing a Web App for that uses the same codebase as the mobile app.

I'm looking for a way to configure some environment variables to recognise if the app is deployed on Mobile App or Web App. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
    rootPage = HomePage;

    constructor(platform: Platform) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {

            if (this.platform.is('android')) {
                console.log("running on Android device!");
            }
            if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
                console.log("running on iOS device!");
            }
            if (this.platform.is('mobileweb')) {
                console.log("running in a browser on mobile!");
            }

        });
    }
}
```